# Can't remove inline event handler on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, events

I want to delete an event handler form a form that contains an inline definition of onsubmit.

```
<form id="loginForm" onsubmit="return performTask(this);">
```

I have already try :

```
$("#loginForm").off("submit")
$("#loginForm").unbind("submit")
$("#loginForm").die("submit")
$("#loginForm")[0].onsubmit = null
$("#loginForm")[0].onsubmit = undefined
$("#loginForm")[0].onSubmit = null
$("#loginForm")[0].onSubmit = undefined
```

And nothing works !

I add my own event listener usin jquery method on() but it is never called. It apear that the ol event listener is executed before mine...

So the question is, is there any way to purge event handlers ? Or much better is there any way to add an event listener that will be call before the inline handler ?

Comment: Try this $("#loginForm").removeAttr("onsubmit")

Comment: You can always put `return false;` inside of your `onsubmit` so it doesn't submit.

Answer (score 1):

When you bind your event using `.on()`, use `removeAttr()`

```
 $('#loginForm').removeAttr('onsubmit').on('....')
```

Answer (score 0):

And the response is that I'm in a Google Chrome Extension and more precisely in a content script and it's not allow to modify any thing except the DOM it self.